# How to generate journal file to azure without creating DHL or Fedex Account?

Tags: azure, service, import, large-data

The name of the journal file, with the .jrn extension. A journal file is generated per drive. We recommend that you use the disk serial number as the journal file name.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNmTK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the complete process to [import data to Azure Blob Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-import-export-data-to-blobs), the account should be **required**. To generate the journal file, you do not need to use FedEx/DHL account.

If you want to create the journal file, refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-import-export-data-to-blobs#step-1-prepare-the-drives) to run the command.

```
./WAImportExport.exe PrepImport /j:<journal file name> /id:session#<session number> /sk:<Storage account key> /t:<Drive letter> /bk:<BitLocker key> /srcdir:<Drive letter>:\ /dstdir:<Container name>/ /skipwrite
```

> **A journal file is created in the same folder where you ran the tool**. Two other files are also created - an .xml file (folder where you run the tool) and a drive-manifest.xml file (folder where data resides).